# Trace / Find Usages of Git Submodule

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-submodules

Is it possible to see which repositories are using a submodule? for instance, if I created a plugin for say 38 projects, would I be able to see which projects are implementing this submodule?

Don't even know if this is possible in git. But maybe on a service level like github or bitbucket?

Open to getting shutdown quickly on this.

Just thinking about this from a maintenance perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using GitHub and have access to the repositories which use the submodule, you can enter the path to your subproject in GitHub's search box. For example, ":foo/bar.git".

This will be matched by the entry in other projects' *.gitmodules* file.

I haven't used BitBucket in years but one would hope it has similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing from Bitbucket Dashboard (Jan '21)

1. Click Search (Top left)
   [image: Bitbucket search menu]

2. Click "Search for code"
3. Search for the submodule's name (this will be at the end of the submodule's "git clone" uri):

`sharedmodulename.git`

Returns a list of all .gitmodules files in repositories which reference a shared module